Randomly "Unable to find the controller for path '/api/auth'" in Tests
I'm using the bundle in a API platform project for auth. In my API tests, I use the configured login endpoint /api/tests.
Bundle configuration:
lexik_jwt_authentication:
  secret_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_SECRET_KEY)%'
  public_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_PUBLIC_KEY)%'
  pass_phrase: '%env(JWT_PASSPHRASE)%'
  api_platform:
    check_path: /api/auth
    username_path: email
    password_path: password

The URL is also defined in my routes.yaml:
api_auth:
  path: /api/auth
  methods: ['POST']

This is my test class with 3 test cases:
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Tests\IntegrationTests\Api\XY;

use ApiPlatform\Symfony\Bundle\Test\ApiTestCase;
use ApiPlatform\Symfony\Bundle\Test\Client;
use Spatie\Snapshots\MatchesSnapshots;

class CanConnectTest extends ApiTestCase
{
    use MatchesSnapshots;

    private Client $client;

    private string $token;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        $client = self::createClient();

        $response1 = $client->request('POST', '/api/auth', [
            'headers' => [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            ],
            'json' => [
                'email' => 'apiuser@domain.de',
                'password' => 'apiuser',
            ],
        ]);
        $json = $response1->toArray();
        self::assertResponseIsSuccessful();
        self::assertArrayHasKey('token', $json);

        $this->token = $json['token'];
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    public function testCanConnectTrue(): void
    {
        $response = $this->client->request(
            'GET',
            'http://localhost/api/audiosus/can_connect/store/7',
            [
                'auth_bearer' => $this->token,
                'headers' => [
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                    'Accept' => 'application/json',
                ],
            ],
        );

        self::assertResponseIsSuccessful();
        self::assertMatchesJsonSnapshot($response->toArray());
    }

    public function testCanConnectFalse(): void
    {
        $response = $this->client->request(
            'GET',
            'http://localhost/api/audiosus/can_connect/store/6',
            [
                'auth_bearer' => $this->token,
                'headers' => [
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                    'Accept' => 'application/json',
                ],
            ],
        );

        self::assertResponseIsSuccessful();
        self::assertMatchesJsonSnapshot($response->toArray());
    }

    public function testCanConnectNotFound(): void
    {
        $this->client->request(
            'GET',
            'http://localhost/api/audiosus/can_connect/store/12312313213',
            [
                'auth_bearer' => $this->token,
                'headers' => [
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                    'Accept' => 'application/json',
                ],
            ],
        );

        self::assertResponseStatusCodeSame(404);
    }
}

When I run the tests, I get randomly errors like this:
1) App\Tests\IntegrationTests\Api\Audiosus\CanConnectTest::testCanConnectFalse
Symfony\Component\HttpClient\Exception\ClientException: An error occurred

Unable to find the controller for path "/api/auth". The route is wrongly configured.

/srv/app/vendor/api-platform/core/src/Symfony/Bundle/Test/Response.php:80
/srv/app/vendor/api-platform/core/src/Symfony/Bundle/Test/Response.php:94
/srv/app/vendor/api-platform/core/src/Symfony/Bundle/Test/Response.php:125
/srv/app/tests/IntegrationTests/Api/XY/CanConnectTest.php:33

2) App\Tests\IntegrationTests\Api\XY\CanConnectTest::testCanConnectTrue
Symfony\Component\HttpClient\Exception\ClientException: An error occurred

Unable to find the controller for path "/api/auth". The route is wrongly configured.

/srv/app/vendor/api-platform/core/src/Symfony/Bundle/Test/Response.php:80
/srv/app/vendor/api-platform/core/src/Symfony/Bundle/Test/Response.php:94
/srv/app/vendor/api-platform/core/src/Symfony/Bundle/Test/Response.php:125
/srv/app/tests/IntegrationTests/Api/XY/CanConnectTest.php:33

or sometimes all the test cases are green, or only one test fails.
Any ideas?
